# cfc arguments struct is getting wrapped in another struct

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When I went to access an argument in a CFC method, I was being told this didn't exist.  When I returned and output my argument struct, I found that it had been placedin another struct with a key of "1"..

For some reason, I now need to access my arguments in this CFC with `arguments[1].name`.

I am passing in a Form struct.  If I dump this form struct before passing into the method, it is just it's own struct.  If I immediately return and output the arguments, it is now nested in this new struct... but I just can't see where or why this would be happening.  I am comparing it to other CFCs that I can access with just argument.???? and they look the same.

The CFC is persistent with ORM, but I have other persistent CFCs that still have arguments as normal.

Any ideas on what might be causing this woiuld be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Comment: How are you calling the method? Are you using myObject.myMethod( form ) or are you using myObject.myMethod( argumentCollection = form )? The former will pass the entire form structure as a single argument and exhibit behavior as you describe, the latter will pass each key in the form structure as an argument to your method

Comment: ah! of course .. was doing the former, not the latter.. forgetting to specify myMethod(ARGUMENTCOLLECTION=form) .. thus the struct becoming argument[1]..  I need to go to bed!  Can you post that as an answer and I will flag it as such.  Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using myObject.myMethod( form ), this will exhibit the behavior you describe.

Try using

```
myObject.myMthod( argumentCollection = form )
```